# Highmaps: Change periods to commas when setOptions wont work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have built a customized map using Highmaps by Highcharts. I need to change the periods (decimal point) to commas. I know how to do it normally using setOptions, like this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    drillUpText: "< < Regresar",
    decimalPoint: ',',
    thousandsSep: '.'
  },
});
```

However, the map's code has been customized to change the tooltip information and setOptions is no longer working to change the periods to commas. I suspect its an easy fix for someone more advanced that I. Are there any JavaScript experts out there that can help me out with this? Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sstoker/L60jg274/

Here's the relevant JS code:

```
$(function() { //For point links

    (function(H) {
        H.Legend.prototype.setItemEvents = null;
    })(Highcharts)

    // Prepare demo data
    // Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
    // See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
    const data = [
        ['mx-3622', 0.00],
        ['mx-bc', 5.59],
        ['mx-bs', 4.05],
        ['mx-so', 4.77],
        ['mx-cl', 6.91],
        ['mx-na', 8.88],
        ['mx-cm', 8.01],
        ['mx-qr', 4.87],
        ['mx-mx', 5.01],
        ['mx-mo', 0.089],
        ['mx-df', 8.12],
        ['mx-qt', 7.32],
        ['mx-tb', 3.17],
        ['mx-cs', 1.15],
        ['mx-nl', 6.88],
        ['mx-si', 6.64],
        ['mx-ch', 2.19],
        ['mx-ve', 0.66],
        ['mx-za', 8.03],
        ['mx-ag', 10],
        ['mx-ja', 3.35],
        ['mx-mi', 3.91],
        ['mx-oa', 0.8],
        ['mx-pu', 1.53],
        ['mx-gr', 0.0],
        ['mx-tl', 2.95],
        ['mx-tm', 5.47],
        ['mx-co', 9.46],
        ['mx-yu', 8.62],
        ['mx-dg', 4.47],
        ['mx-gj', 8.33],
        ['mx-sl', 4.35],
        ['mx-hg', 4.75]
    ];

    const data1 = [
        ['mx-3622', 0.0],
        ['mx-bc', 13],
        ['mx-bs', 21],
        ['mx-so', 17],
        ['mx-cl', 10],
        ['mx-na', 3],
        ['mx-cm', 8],
        ['mx-qr', 16],
        ['mx-mx', 15],
        ['mx-mo', 31],
        ['mx-df', 6],
        ['mx-qt', 9],
        ['mx-tb', 24],
        ['mx-cs', 28],
        ['mx-nl', 11],
        ['mx-si', 12],
        ['mx-ch', 26],
        ['mx-ve', 30],
        ['mx-za', 7],
        ['mx-ag', 1],
        ['mx-ja', 23],
        ['mx-mi', 22],
        ['mx-oa', 29],
        ['mx-pu', 27],
        ['mx-gr', 32],
        ['mx-tl', 25],
        ['mx-tm', 14],
        ['mx-co', 2],
        ['mx-yu', 4],
        ['mx-dg', 19],
        ['mx-gj', 5],
        ['mx-sl', 20],
        ['mx-hg', 18]
    ];


    // Create the chart
    var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#f3f7fa',
            map: 'countries/mx/mx-all',
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },



        plotOptions: { //For point links
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function(e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
            map: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            $('#map1').trigger(this['hc-key']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        },

        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: 0
                }
            },
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
                            this.renderer.image('http://165.22.82.145/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/IDDMEX-Logo.svg',
                                480, // x
                                335, // y
                                75, // width
                                40, // height
                            ).add();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },


        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: false,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0,
            maxColor: 'blue',

            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    console.log(this)
                }
            },

            dataClasses: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 3.000,
                color: '#6497b1'
            }, {
                from: 3.001,
                to: 4.500,
                color: '#005b96'
            }, {
                from: 4.510,
                to: 7.000,
                color: '#03396c'
            }, {
                from: 7.001,
                to: 10.000,
                color: '#011f4b'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            title: {
                text: 'Desarrollo',
                style: {
                    color: ( // theme
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title.style &&
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.title.style.color
                    ) || 'black'
                }
            },
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            floating: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            valueDecimals: 3,
            symbolRadius: 5,
            symbolHeight: 14
        },



        series: [{
            keys: ['hc-key', 'value', 'rank'],
            data: data,
            name: 'Índice 2018',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#f3bbd3'
                },
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }],

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: ' {point.name} {point.value} <br>Ranking: {point.rank}',
            pointFormatter: function() {
                var firstRow = (this['hc-key'] === 'mx-df') ?
                    "CDMX" :
                    this.name;
                firstRow = firstRow + " " + this.value;
                var secondRow = "Ranking: " + this.rank;
                return (firstRow + "<br />" + secondRow);
            }
        },

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setOptions` usage is the correct solution. Next step is to use `Highcharts.numberFormat` function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay8m4pug/

Relevant code:

```js
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {
        decimalPoint: ',',
        ...
      }
    });

    ...

        tooltip: {
            ...
            pointFormatter: function() {
                ...
                firstRow = firstRow + " " + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value);
                ...
            }
        },
```